# When will the A Song of Ice and Fire series be completed?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I enjoy the Game of Thrones TV Series, and am ready to try the books.

However, having waited over 15 years for Stephen King to finish The Dark Tower; I would like to know when the entire series will be available.

This question has two parts:

**1. How many books are planned for the entire series?**
**2. When will they be finished?**

Comment: It ends when the last main character dies...JUST KIDDING!  Here's seven more main characters!

Comment: Oh crap, I just started the series (well, I'm on book 4 now...) and I thought it was over in _A Dance with Dragons_! I ended up waiting 3 (4? too many) years for Wheel of Time to end.

Comment: I think I speak for every "Song of Fire and Ice" fan when I say "Hopefully, before GRR Martin dies."

Comment: @BraveLilToaster Oh that is just too true...

Comment: I have no hope that the series will be finished before GRRM dies. Seeing how he is an older fat guy...He will pull a Jordan on us, of that I am certain.

Comment: [When the series becomes unprofitable](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/The_Simpsons_138th_Episode_Spectacular/Quotes).

Comment: @BraveLilToaster what is this "Song of Fire and Ice" you speak of? as a self-proclaimed fan you should at least call it "Song of Ice and Fire" :P

Comment: This is exactly what I asked myself 17 years ago after reading the teaser for _A Feast for Crows_ at the end of _A Storm of Swords_. I vowed to just give up the series. Then _Bush V. Gore_ distracted me. Five years passed. I found myself buying _A Feast for Crows_.

Comment: @Jakob: he’s gonna dance a Dornish jig at your funeral bro.

Comment: This is the first rhetorical question I've seen asked on SFF-SE.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are supposed to be a total of 7 books in the "A Song of Ice and Fire" series. But could grow to 8. Originally it was going to be a trilogy, then grew to 4, then 6, then 7...  And it could be a long wait! Here's the [chronology so far](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire#Publishing_history):

1. A Game of Thrones   August 1996
2. A Clash of Kings    February 1999
3. A Storm of Swords   November 2000
4. A Feast for Crows   November 2005
5. A Dance with Dragons    July 2011
6. The Winds of Winter (Forthcoming)
7. A Dream of Spring   (Forthcoming)

Comment: for comparison, The Wheel of Time series was "supposed to be" 3 books, then 6, then 12 books and ended up being 14. So, it will end up being as many books as the author feels he needs to finish the story (or, if you're more the cynical type, as many as he can get paid for.)

Comment: In the [2012 interview](http://www.adriasnews.com/2012/10/george-r-r-martin-interview.html?spref=tw) where GRRM guesstimated 2014, he implied that his guess may be optimistic: "I really look forward to publishing it in 2014, but I am really bad for predictions...."

Comment: Books 4 and 5 clearly indicate that GRRM is going to spin this out as long as he possibly can.

Comment: There are probably going to be books until he dies, He will never give this up. The series is to popular, its like Harry Potter with grossness.

Comment: Still 73 days left for *The Winds of Winter* to come out in 2014. I wonder what odds you can get on that happening.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: There is no chance in frozen hell for *The Winds of Winter* to come out in 2014. With one month left before end-of-year holiday season, the book would have to have been fully in editing mode for quite some time for it to be able to come out for it.

Comment: It seems even in 2015 is rather too optimistic now...

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - they really missed the boat with WoT, too. The series having 13 books to it would have been a nice symmetry with there being 13 Forsaken, 13 Aes Sedai in a circle, etc. etc. Plus, honestly, at least a full book worth of useless fluff could be eliminated easily.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite 2016...Still no prospect of WoW being released xD

Comment: As of December 21st, 2016, there is still no hint of a release date. Better start appealing to the Seven or even the Lord of Light to get GRRM to speed things up a bit.

Comment: @Aegon: 2017, and I believe this is as far as things have gotten: http://grrm.livejournal.com/515302.html?thread=25561062#t25561062

Comment: @Aegon: 2018’s a-comin’! [The Winds of Winter will totally 100%* come with it!](http://grrm.livejournal.com/544709.html) (* Not totally or 100%.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Hah. At least the released prequel was good. There are rumors that GRRM is gonna publish something, anything with the title TWOW on insistence of his publishers who want to capitalize on the show's hype before it ends.